# ARM-Assembly: Arithmetic Shift / Logical Shift

Tags: assembly, arm, shift

I'm a bit stuck finding out in which way those 2 operations are different. So I read that Arithmetic shift is basically the same as Logical with the only difference, that it somehow keeps the highest or signed bit.

So when I do LSL #2 on 101110 assuming that this binary is a unsigned one, the result would be: 111000 and the carry bit would be set in the CPSR, right?

When I perform ASL #2 on the same number, what would be the result and how does it keep the signed bit? What about ASR #2 on the above binary? Would the result be 101011?

Unfortunately I've only found a really rough description about Arithmetic shift. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ASL and LSL are synonyms. The difference comes with ASR/LSR, where ASR will copy the original most upper bit all "new" upper bits. This is useful in computing with signed values in two-complement representation.

Comment: @Masta79 So the difference would be: LSR 101110 -> 010111, ASR 101110 -> 110111 ?

Comment: Correct (if you had 6bit registers)

Comment: @Masta79 Thank you, finally understood it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the registers and assembly languages instructions have no idea whether you consider a particular value to be signed or unsigned. If you apply an arithmetic right shift to an "unsigned" register value the result may not be valid.

Comment: See also http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDDCIF.html, where they document how ASR shifts in copies of the MSB (sign bit), while LSR shifts in zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples don't make much sense since your numbers are 6bit only so 31st bit will always be `0`.

`ASL` is a synonym for `LSL` and you can see shift operations behaviour in [official ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/CIHDDCIF.html) or this [ARM reference site](http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/ch-3.html).

Comment: yes, maybe a bit unfortunate referring to ARM here, of course I assumed it were 6 bit and not 32 bit arm registers.

Answer (score 5):

I had hard time to understand the real difference between LSR and ASR but hope this image helps you to understand the same.
In LSR(`Logical Shift Right`) the MSB(`Most Significant Bit`) is replaced by 0 where as In ASR(`Arithematic Shift Right`) MSB is same as the earlier MSB before being shifted .(Similar for Left Shift)
ASR is useful in computing with signed values in two-complement representation.

[image]

Comment: Did you copy that from somewhere?  If so, you should include a link to the source.  (Not just to the image in imgur).

Comment: From some book and ppt that my teacher gave me I can give you her phone number if you are interested in knowing but she's 65.`I would have already mentioned had been it possible` @PeterCordes